# Heroku NodeJs Postgres Heroku pg:psql - Connection Timeout

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm following the tutorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

I have everything working until the provosion a database step. My code is exactly the same as theirs, but for some reason I can't connect to

```
heroku pg:psql
```

It says Connecting to DATABASE_URL and then the connection times out. Does anyone know what's happening? I set the DATABASE_URL following the format:

```
"postgres://*USERNAME*:*PASSWORD*@*HOST*:*PORT:/*DATABASE*"
```

Comment: there should be no `:` after the `PORT`.

Comment: Weird, after trying the entire day it works now without changing the ':'. But thanks anyway!